# I can't use "from math import sqrt" on Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, sqrt, math.sqrt

I'm new to this site, I'm recently trying to learn how to code in Python again, and now I'm doing an exercise that I could complete, but it's happening something that is annoying me.
I can import math successfully, but somehow, VSCode just doesn't want to recognize "from math import sqrt". Here's my code so anyone can help me. Thank you.

```py
import math  # (from math import sqrt would be here, but doesn't work so I put import math)

a = int(input('Digite o primeiro número: '))
b = int(input('Digite o segundo número: '))

c = a**2+b**2
resultado = math.sqrt(c)

print(f'O comprimento da hipotenusa é de {resultado}')
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What error do you get when you try `from math import sqrt`?

Comment: How do you know it doesn't work? See how to create a [mcve]. Edit the question.

Comment: Please show the full error message. I suspect you have called one of your own scripts "math.py"  and now that gets imported.

Comment: I dont get any error trying to from math import sqrt, VSCode simply doesn't recognize, like it doesnt exist.

Comment: Then my math.sqrt just dont get recognized

Comment: Sorry guys, understand it wrong, Im not a native english speaker hahaha

Comment: name 'math' is not defined
  File "C:\Users\Luchaos\Desktop\Programs\Scripts-Python\desafio17.py", line 7, in <module>
    resultado = math.sqrt(c)

Comment: if you do `from math import sqrt` then you have imported only `sqrt` and not `math`. So in this case `resultado = math.sqrt(c)` should be `resultado = sqrt(c)` instead.

Comment: oh damn, now i get it, thank you bro

Answer (score 0):

If you do from math import sqrt then you have imported only sqrt and not math. So in this case `resultado = math.sqrt(c)` should be `resultado = sqrt(c)` instead.

Mathias answered it in the comments; thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you dont need the math module, you can instead do:

```
c = (a**2+b**2)**0.5
```

as square rooting a number is equal to power it to 1/2.